# Generating infinite parallel Stream

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I'm Trying to find a good way for creating an infinite paraller Stream.
Right Now my code looks like this:

```
Stream<List<Integer>> lists =
                Stream.iterate(true, x -> true)
                        .parallel()
                        .map(x ->
                                IntStream.rangeClosed(1, population)
                                        .boxed()
                                        /* ... */
                                        .collect(toList()))
                        .limit(50_000);
```

The **boolean x** value is totally pointless.
What I actually would want to be able to do would look something like this **pseudo code**:

```
Stream<List<Integer>> lists1 =
            Stream.parallel().generate(() ->
                    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, population)
                            .boxed()
                            /* ... */
                            .collect(toList()))
                    .limit(50_000);
```

Any good hints are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Could you explain in English what you want to do? It will be clearer that trying to interpret the pseudo code.

Comment: When you create an infinite stream to limit it afterwards to a finite count, you are effectively create a finite stream, just in an inefficient manner. It’s especially wasteful as you are going to do the same thing 50,000 times. Instead of doing it in parallel you should think about doing it *only once*, using the result with `Collections.nCopies`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
List<List<Integer>> res = Stream.generate(() ->
                                             // ...
                                         ).parallel()
                                .limit(50_000)
                                .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Does this also make all the execution before the parallel() call parallel?

Comment: @Nabuska: the placement of `parallel()` is completely irrelevant. The only thing that matters is that it’s there. However, it's still a very inefficient way of creating a list of identical elements…